# What packages do I need to install to serve php pages from apache2 on Fedora 17?

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, php5

This seems like it should be easy to answer, but as a php newbie, I can't find out what exactly I need to install.

Some sites recommend just **httpd**, **php** and **php-common**; other suggestions include **php-fpm** and **mod_fastcgi**, as well as a bunch of php packages.

My goal is to be able to set up my dev machine and an amazon EC2 instance to be as similar as possible.

What do I need to install?

Comment: This looks more like a question for StackOverflow than for ServerFault, because as far as I can see you're trying to learn PHP and not installing/using some PHP based software. Anyway, to make my comment more useful, installing the `php` package on Fedora should be enough for starting things up.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu No, this is about AWS instances and how to deploy them with a set of software reproducibly.

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen - I guess the question isn't as clear as it should be, but what I'm looking for is details on the required stack for hosting php - web server, plugins, and the php runtime.

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora 17 it's sufficient to install the `php` package. This pulls in all necessary dependencies, including Apache.

On previous versions of Fedora, and current versions of RHEL, you need to install `mod_php`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to install the necessary packages via the `user-data` from AWS. To be honest, I invested an hour of research into it: I did this before with Ubuntu just to learn that it doesn't work like that with Fedora. They have their own funky way of dealing with user-data, and until now I didn't grok how the utilize /etc/cloud. The documentation is, midly said, crap. At this moment I'm talking to the Fedora-cloud people and I hope I'll be getting some insight... I'm really curious myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try AMI `ami-2ea50247` from the [Fedora Cloudimage](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cloud_images) site.

Then use as `user-data` in the AWS-console:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y install httpd php php-common php-fpm mod_fcgid
```

I just tried it because I was curious. Works like charm. Thanks to `gholms` from `#fedora-cloud` on Freenode for the hint about adding the hashbang.

If you need more machines, just "launch more like this".

You might want to add this to user-data:

```
chkconfig httpd on
service httpd start
```

To make it start automatically and right away after instance creation. Your pick.