# libphp.so is missing in the oracle linux 9, is there any alternative to let httpd handle php page?

Tags: php, httpd, oracle-linux

I do find a lot similar problems on CentOS in this forum, and I tried to follow any suggestions mentioned in their answer, however, none solves my problem. Therefore I’m opening this question for platform specific solution.

I have downloaded `httpd`, `php`, `php-common`, `php-cli`. From [some answer](https://serverfault.com/a/437864/1002498) it seems having `php` installed would be already sufficient, but the PHP file is not handled by php. I tried to search for `libphp`, `*php*` with `yum` and `dnf` command, but returned result does not have any match to httpd/apache module for php. On ubuntu server I do find similar module mentioned in other answer and php is working properly to phrase the page. I also set `fileMatch` to set handler, but I think due to the missing `libphp8.so` module it is not working.

From the search suggested in the comment below, I found `php-embedded` is the only package that provide `libphp.so` or `libphp-8.0.so`. However, neither has symbol `php_module`, but both are callable by `php_embed_module`. So I added this in the config file, but `apachectl configtest` shows it is not an apache module. The answer below has suggested `php-fpm`, but from the install utility it seems to be Nginx-based.

I was wondering since Red hat and Oracle are both CentOS like, can I just add RHEL 9's repo to `dnf` and check if they have a compatible module. But would that has compatibility concerns?

The HTTPD version is (`httpd -v`):

```bash
Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Oracle Linux Server)
```

The PHP version is:

```bash
PHP 8.0.20
```

and The system version is (`cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY_NAME`):

```bash
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 9.1"
```

Comment: You can search which package to install with `yum whatprovides libphp.so`.

Comment: @setenforce1 That returns `Error: No matches found.`... But luckily adding `*/` helps. Thanks for the comment

Comment: We're not a forum.

Comment: I found that it was due to repeated httpd configuration, the handler for `.php` file was set twice referring the same handler

Answer (score 0):

You did not set your repo properly. Or do not search for the proper package. [Here](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/x86_64/index.html) is the repo for Oracle Linux 9 and as you can see there are `php` packages.

Check [here](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html) for Oracle procedure how to install it.

You can also check [here](https://techviewleo.com/install-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-on-oracle-linux/) how to install php on OracleLinux.

And BTW check for `php-fpm`

Comment: No, I’ve installed `php` but there is no `libphp.so` library for apache

Comment: I also checked if there is `mod_php.so` but that’s also not the case

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Your latter way needs to disable SELinux Policy. and the first guide is also only installing php (which I did), but I do found, with `dnf whatprovides` the `php-embedded` to be the right one to install.

Comment: Just want to add, the library comes with `php-embedded` is not a apache module (`configtest` has warned me), and does not have `php_module` or `mod_php` in it's symbol (from `nm -gD libphp-8.0.so` it seems only `php_embed_module` is suitable). Moreover, the `php-fpm` you mentioned appears to work with Nginx (since the install requires additional `nginx-filesystem` package)